# Scala: reference an xml literal from another xml

Tags: xml, scala

Is it possible to reference one xml variable from another xml? E.g. is it possible to do something like this:

```
val foo = <foo> foo text </foo>

val bar = <bar> + foo + </bar>
```

so that bar will contain foo as it's child:

```
<bar><foo>foo text</foo></bar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `<bar>{foo}</bar>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
val bar = <bar>{foo}</bar>
```